# How can I add content to a JPanel only AFTER it has been layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I need to display an image inside a JPanel (which itself is placed in several layers of JPanels) and I want to resize the image to fit the width of the JPanel. Now at the time when I add the Image to the JPanel, the JPanel's getWidth() equals the screen width and so the image gets resized to the screen width. But after the Jpanel has been added to its parent JPanel the width has changed and therefore the image is to large for the JPanel's width.

I would like to resize and add the image only after the JPanel has been layout, so I get the proper width of the panel and can resize the image accordingly.

How can I accomplish this? Is there any event like afterLayout()?

Comment: what do you mean by "add the image"? Core JPanel has no api for doing such a thingy ... In SwingX' JXPanel you would set a ImagePainter (as the panel's backgroundPainter) with its stretched property set to true: it'll auto-scale itself to always fit the panel size

Comment: I'd tend to calculate the dimensions on `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could use a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to do that. LayoutManager should call setSize method while layouting components, so you should be able to be notified of such modifications.

The method you are looking for is :

```
void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){}
```

So implement ComponentListener interface and add it to the desired Component through [addComponentListener()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addComponentListener%28java.awt.event.ComponentListener%29) method:

```
JPanel panel;
...
panel.addComponentListener(new YourClassImplementingComponentListener());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ComponentListener` and listen to `ComponentResized` method. In that write your logic to resize the image according to size of panel. When the pannel will resize the image will also resize accordingly.

Comment: hmm ... this differs from and extends @Heisenbug 's answer in that ...?